# Percentage of factor levels the same between factor levels of second variable

Tags: r, dplyr, diff, na, factors

Below is a brief reproducible example, with a brief explanation.

`age_group` is a two-level factor. `variant` is a factor with a different amount of factors per `age_group`. `prob` is the probability of the respective variant by `age_group`.

```
dat = tribble(
  
  ~age_group, ~variant, ~prob,
  "< 30", "Frohes neues Jahr", 0.429,
  "< 30", "Gutes neues Jahr", 0.143,
  "< 30", "Prosit Neujahr", 0.429,
  "> 50", "Frohes neues Jahr", 0.1,
  "> 50", "Gesundes neues Jahr", 0.1,
  "> 50", "Gutes neues Jahr", 0.2,
  "> 50", "Prosit Neujahr", 0.6
  
)
```

I want to compute the difference between the respective variants per age group. I can do that using the following code:

```
dat1 %>% 
  group_by(variant, zip, country_code) %>% 
  mutate(prob_diff = c(diff(prob), NA)) %>% 
  relocate(prob_diff, .after = prob)
```

However, I want to differentiate in the NAs: I.e., for the factor levels in `variant` that are the same between the two `age_group` levels, I want the NAs. For the factor levels that are **different** between the two `age_group` levels (in this case, "Gesundes neues Jahr" exists in the "> 50" level, but not in the "< 30" level), I would like the new value in the `prob_diff` column to be 1.

Is this possible? If anyone could help, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Can you fix the example code that you provided? Both `zip` and `country_code` aren't available in the object `dat`. Should it just be `group_by(variant)`?
Also `dat1` isn't the name of the object you provided to us. Should we just be using `dat` instead?

Comment: Also, when you say "I want the NAs", do you mean that you want to see the value of `NA` in the rows where a `variant` is in multiple `age_group`'s?